# VBA: Loop does not include last 2 rows

Tags: vba, excel

Problem:
I have a code that does everything it should, only it does not 'finish' its work. Whenever I run this code, it seems that the last 2 rows are not included.

Code:

```
Sub List()

Dim sStDev As Worksheet: Set sStDev = Sheets("StDev")
Dim sResult As Worksheet: Set sResult = Sheets("Large")
Dim sQuart As Worksheet: Set sQuart = Sheets("Quintile")
Dim sReturn As Worksheet: Set sReturn = Sheets("Return")

Dim j As Long

Const colDate As Long = 1
Const rowStDevFirst As Long = 2
Const rowResultFirst As Long = 2
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = sReturn.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim rowResult As Long: rowResult = rowResultFirst

j = 2

Dim i As Long: For i = rowStDevFirst To LastRow

Dim colResult As Long: colResult = 1
sResult.Cells(rowResult, colResult).Value = sStDev.Cells(i, colDate).Value
colResult = colResult + 1

For j = 1 To 792
If sStDev.Cells(i, j).Value >= sQuart.Range("F2").Offset(i, 0) And sStDev.Cells(i, j).Value <= sQuart.Range("G2").Offset(i, 0) Then
    sResult.Cells(rowResult, colResult).Value = sReturn.Cells(i, j).Value
colResult = colResult + 1

End If


Next j

rowResult = rowResult + 1

Next i

MsgBox "Listed"


End Sub
```

How can I make this code include my last two rows as well?

Thank you in advance!

File: [File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3yagZfhPjfgcGJTa2xYQnA1X0E/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: In my code the "i" is meant to be the loop through the rows (first loop) and the "j" is meant to be the loop through the columns (second loop). So it would go through all rows in a column and then move to the next column and so on.

Comment: It could be caused by the contents of the Excel sheet causing the If statements to skip. Without the excel sheet we can't say for sure. Set break-points in code and debug.

Comment: Is there content in the last two rows in column `A`?

Comment: You should add sample data, expected results and actual results.

Comment: Your code is quite difficult to read and I'm not even sure which module I'm looking in as you re-use `Sub` names everywhere but if it is in the `ListLarge` module the loop runs correctly and runs to row `216`

Comment: Yes I should probably change the Sub names, apologies I only recently started coding with VBA so I am still learning. The `ListLarge` does give values to row `216` but just in column A. It stops giving values in the other columns starting from row `208`.

Comment: The loop is running as it should be, however your `If` statement is returning false which is why these aren't getting populated

Comment: Your `Quintile` sheet ends at row 209. Therefore you're trying to compare a date against an empty cell so the `If` statement returns `false` and doesn't populate your `Large` sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you try to fill out the Large sheet with these values from Return sheet for which the corresponding value in StDev is between F and G values in Quintile for each row.

It's Ok, but you shouldn't offset the values in Quintile by i as even for the second row you get the Quintile!F4 and G4 instead of F2 and G2.

So to fix it you should change `sQuart.Range("F2").Offset(i, 0)` to `sQuart.Range("F2").Offset(i-2, 0)`

and the same for column G: `Offset(i, 0)` should be `Offset(i-2, 0)`